# Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:lintVitalRelease' with some other errors

Tags: java, android, android-studio, apk, signed-apk

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:lintVitalRelease'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':app:debugAndroidTestRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve androidx.concurrent:concurrent-futures:{strictly 1.0.0}.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Cannot find a version of 'androidx.concurrent:concurrent-futures' that satisfies the version constraints: 
           Dependency path 'DBRL ORDERS:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5' --> 'androidx.test:core:1.5.0' --> 'androidx.concurrent:concurrent-futures:1.1.0'
           Constraint path 'DBRL ORDERS:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.concurrent:concurrent-futures:{strictly 1.0.0}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.0.0
           Dependency path 'DBRL ORDERS:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1' --> 'androidx.core:core:1.9.0' --> 'androidx.concurrent:concurrent-futures:1.0.0'

   > Could not resolve androidx.concurrent:concurrent-futures:1.1.0.
     Required by:
         project :app > androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5 > androidx.test:core:1.5.0
      > Cannot find a version of 'androidx.concurrent:concurrent-futures' that satisfies the version constraints: 
           Dependency path 'DBRL ORDERS:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5' --> 'androidx.test:core:1.5.0' --> 'androidx.concurrent:concurrent-futures:1.1.0'
           Constraint path 'DBRL ORDERS:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.concurrent:concurrent-futures:{strictly 1.0.0}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.0.0
           Dependency path 'DBRL ORDERS:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1' --> 'androidx.core:core:1.9.0' --> 'androidx.concurrent:concurrent-futures:1.0.0'

   > Could not resolve androidx.concurrent:concurrent-futures:1.0.0.
     Required by:
         project :app > androidx.core:core:1.9.0
      > Cannot find a version of 'androidx.concurrent:concurrent-futures' that satisfies the version constraints: 
           Dependency path 'DBRL ORDERS:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5' --> 'androidx.test:core:1.5.0' --> 'androidx.concurrent:concurrent-futures:1.1.0'
           Constraint path 'DBRL ORDERS:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.concurrent:concurrent-futures:{strictly 1.0.0}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.0.0
           Dependency path 'DBRL ORDERS:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1' --> 'androidx.core:core:1.9.0' --> 'androidx.concurrent:concurrent-futures:1.0.0'


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
```

I've been getting this error when I am generating a signed apk in android studio.

I tried generating a signed apk and this came out as the output.

Here is my gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 31
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.dbrlorders"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
}
```

Comment: Please don't ever write anything IN ALL CAPS.

Comment: What are the entries in your `repositories` section in build.gradle?